# Variable = null in method declaration? What does it mean and how is this method called?

Tags: c#

As I was browsing some code today I stumbled upon the following method declaration

`public List<Tuple<DataTable, string>> GetFileData(string directoryPath, string columnName = null)`

I built something like it and attempted to call this method using a single parameter, figuring that since I've declared `columnName = null` I would be able to *optionally* send in an argument here.  Not the case, apparently.

I made an interface

```
public interface IExcelDataExtractor
{
    List<Tuple<DataTable, string>> GetFileData(string directoryPath, string columnName);
}
```

and implemented it

```
public class ExcelDataExtractor : IExcelDataExtractor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Loops through each file in given directory and extracts the data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directoryPath">the directory in which to look for the excel files</param>
    /// <param name="columnName">extractor will look for a sheet with the columName present to pull data from in case of multiple sheets, or a single sheet if null is passed</param>
    public List<Tuple<DataTable, string>> GetFileData(string directoryPath, string columnName = null)
    {
        //Initiate list of tuples
        List<Tuple<DataTable, string>> dataTableWithFileName = new List<Tuple<DataTable, string>>();

        //Loop through each file in directory with a filter on *.xls*, this should catch both .xls and .xlsx
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.xls*"))
        {
            DataSet ds;
            DataTable dt;

            ds = Read(file);
            dt = ExtractDataByColumn(ds, columnName);
            if (dt is null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            dataTableWithFileName.Add(Tuple.Create(dt, file));
        }

        return dataTableWithFileName;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads excel files and sends data to dataset with each sheet being a data table within the sheet
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">file to open and add to the dataset</param>
    /// <returns>returns the dataset from the file</returns>
    private DataSet Read(string file)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true
                    }
                };

                return reader.AsDataSet(conf);
            }
        }
    }


    private DataTable ExtractDataByColumn(DataSet dataSet, string columnName = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
        {
            foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;
                if (columns.Contains(columnName))
                {
                    return table;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //If no columnName is given & more than 1 sheet is present, we want this to fail, else, return the single table
            foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 1)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return table;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I try to call this method in the following way I get an error:

`GetFileData(directory);`

`There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'columnName' of 'IExcelDataExtractor.GetFileData(string, string)'`

When I call it like this, it works:

`GetFileData(directory, null);`

So I have two questions:

- What does putting `= null` after a variable in a method declaration do?
- Why is this even needed if I presumably need to still send in a corresponding `null` when calling this method?

Comment: Is there a compiler error?  It works fine for me just calling it as `GetFileData("");`

Comment: It should be optional _(using the default when not specified)_. **But....** for C# 8.0, it **might** be wrong. Because the declaration should be probably  `string? columnName = null`  _(more info at [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references))_

Comment: *"Not the case, apparently"* Please elaborate on what you mean here.

Comment: Based solely on that signature, that second parameter *is* optional.  If it is not optional when you try to call it, there is something else relevant that you haven't shown us.  Perhaps you have an interface for that method but the interface doesn't specify an optional parameter?

Comment: What is the exact message you are getting?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's new, and `string?` is in the official documentation for C# 8, linked in the comment you replied to.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) he has just after the code sample. This is valid in C# 8

Comment: Added the error I get when I attempt to build the solution.

Comment: The up comming version C# 8.0 will have [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). You can choose whether a reference type accepts nulls or not.

Comment: @Mkalafut, can you show us IExcelDataExtractor?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Standby, editing.

Comment: Edited to add the entire interface & class.  Really this is an isolated issue and the code does work when I pass a null, but I'm just wondering why I need to even pass a null if I'm defaulting the parameter to `= null` in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What does putting = null after a variable in a method declaration do?**

It makes is optional when calling the method. So you can call this method like this:

```
GetFileData("path", "columnName")
```

Or like this:

```
GetFileData("path")
```

And both are valid. In the second case, `columnName` will just be null.

**Why is this even needed if I presumably need to still send in a corresponding null when calling this method?**

Hopefully, I already answered that? :)

Instead of using `NULL` you could also use a value...

```
GetFileData(string directoryPath, string columnName = "foobar")
```

And in this case, "foobar" will be the default value if none is provided when making the call.

**EDIT:**

Ah!  `IExcelDataExtractor`.
Somewhere there is an interface that is requiring the second parameter.  Can you show us that interface?

**EDIT 2:**

`IExcelDataExtractor` is an Interface. An interface is like a contract. Any class that implements it MUST have the methods that are created in the interface.

Inside `IExcelDataExtractor`, the method `GetFileData(string, string)' does NOT have the second string defined as optional.  This means that even though the actual method might try and make it optional, it can't override its original definition (ie: contract) inside IExcelDataExtractor.

This is why you get the error when you call `GetFileData` without the second parameter.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't expect this to get so much traction so quickly I figured it would just be a simple throwaway question.  I've added additional info.  I assumed that it made the parameter optional, so question 2 only really stands if I'm doing nothing incorrectly and `null` is still required to be passed.  If I just missed something in order to call it as `GetFileData("path")`, then my second question is basically not needed.

Comment: Perfect.  I would have expected the compiler to scream at me way earlier than it did if that's the case.  Thanks for the explanation.  Essentially just adding the `= null` in the interface definition would solve my problem, then?

Comment: Yeah that is odd that it even let you compile.  And yes, you can either change the interface or... whoever coded the method just did it wrong, and you can remove the `= null'.  Depends on what you need.  It might be that the interface is correct, and the second parameter should always be required.

Comment: Yeah I inherited this code after our junior developer quit last week.  I've been trying to wrap my head around what the heck the point of this was so thanks so much for helping me.